How to turn hand-drawn symbols into LaTeX code (something like detexify) in Ubuntu?
Detexify is a software that can turn handdrawn symbols into LaTeX code. It has a proprietary Mac app. How to install something similar in Ubuntu?


There is an app called Hieroglyphic which can do this. It is based on TeX-Match.

You can install it using Flatpak. Here is how to set up flatpak, if you already haven't.
flatpak install flathub io.github.finefindus.Hieroglyphic

There is also an unofficial PPA (maintained by me), for Ubuntu 24.04 and later versions.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/hieroglyphic
sudo apt update
sudo apt install hieroglyphic

